# Titanium webview setHtml html link variabl "not found" in android

Tags: webview, titanium

Titanium webview setHtml html link variabl "not found" in android

i have a simple web view code

```
webView.setHtml('<div id="framecontent"><iframe src="jq/single.html?rid=4&sid=3" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0></iframe></div>');
```

i use i frame so i can pass data via the url

it work fine in iOS

but in android it show "not found message" it can't find it in its location, when i remove this `?rid=4&sid=3` it loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a leading slash: /jq/single.html...

I had such issues, too and found that on Android a leading slash is needed.